# Поиск контуров на изображении

Tags: c++, opencv, обработка-изображений

Добрый вечер!

Работаю над задачей распознавания текста. 
Использую OpenCV.

Проблема такая: Есть текст(ниже), я хочу выделить каждый отдельный символ с помощью метода:

```
CVAPI(int)  cvFindContours( CvArr* image, CvMemStorage* storage, CvSeq** first_contour,
                            int header_size CV_DEFAULT(sizeof(CvContour)),
                            int mode CV_DEFAULT(CV_RETR_LIST),
                            int method CV_DEFAULT(CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE),
                            CvPoint offset CV_DEFAULT(cvPoint(0,0)));
```

Выделять(выделяю только внешние контуры - `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL`) и прорисовывать контуры получается отлично, но проблема в том, что `cvFindContours(...)` возвращает найденные контуры в произвольном порядке, но для моей задачи порядок очень важен. Вопрос в том, как восстанавливать порядок обхода контуров или как сделать так, чтобы `cvFindContours(...)` возвращал контуры в том порядке, который на картинке, а не так как ему вздумается?

При необходимости могу привести код.

[image: исходное изображение]

[image: изображение с нарисованными контурами]

Answer (score 2):

### Возможно ответ довольно банален, но можно просто отсортировать найденные прямоугольники по возрастанию x-координаты.

Единственное, в чём могут возникнуть трудности - если текст многоэтажный, тут могу посоветовать из своей практики написать алгоритм анализа, наподобие трассировки целей, который начиная с самого левого контура будет искать следующего кандидата на слово из раствора по определённому углу (скажем, чтобы тангенс угла уплывания не превышал 45 градусов), и так пройтись по массиву прямоугольников, пока все не исчерпаем.

В нашем проекте этот алгоритм идеально нас удовлетворяет. Думаю, даже в самой примитивной форме (как я описал выше) он будет отличным первым приближением.